# How to find out which AppPool is associated with which w3wp Process?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

I used to do this:

> How to attach to the correct process
>   in IIS6
>
> IIS6 uses seperate process for each
>   AppPool, usefully these all have the
>   same name - w3wp.exe.
>
> To determine which AppPool? the
>   application is using right
>   click>properties on the directory in
>   InetMgr? and look at the AppPool list
>   at the bottom.
>
> To determine which process matches
>   which AppPool type the following at
>   the command prompt:
>
> ```
> iisapps.vbs
> ```
>
> You may get a message box asking if
>   you want to change your default
>   VBScript provider to CScript. If for
>   some reason you don't, type:
>
> ```
> cscript iisapps.vbs
> ```
>
> This will list the process ids for
>   each app pool, then all you have to do
>   is match the process id in visual
>   studio's attach to process screen.
>
> Example:
>
> > W3WP.exe PID: 5124   AppPoolId:
> >     SharePoint - 80 W3WP.exe PID: 4236
> >     AppPoolId: DefaultAppPool W3WP.exe
> >     PID: 728   AppPoolId: SharePoint
> >     Central Administration v3 W3WP.exe
> >     PID: 4128   AppPoolId: ReportServer

But this doesnt seem to work on Server 2008. Is there a better method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv`

`appcmd list wp`